# iphone/ipod mobile safari causes video element to disappear on rotation

Tags: iphone, ipod

I am writing a very simple website that displays a video. I have separate stylesheets for the different rotation states of the device, like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="portrait-style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:landscape)" href="landscape-style.css"/>
```

The sheets load and display the content properly when the user first navigates to the site in the respective orientation. However, when the user changes orientation, the video element in the following code disappears, while all other styling for the orientation is correctly applied.

```
<video id="mainvideo" width="640" height="480" controls preload="auto">

        <source src="output.ogv"  type="video/ogg" />       
        <source src="output.mp4"  type="video/mp4" />       

        <object width="640" height="480" data="flowplayer-3.2.5.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">  
            <param name="movie" value="flowplayer-3.2.5.swf" />  
            <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"/> 
            <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>
            <param name="flashvars" value="config={'clip':{'url':'output.flv', 'autoPlay':false, 'autoBuffering':true}}" />
        </object>

        <div id="trollface">
        <p>You do not have Adobe flash player installed on your browser. You may download it <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/">here</a>.</p>
        </br>
        <p>Alternatively, you may also use a modern, standards-compliant browser (such as <a href="http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/">firefox</a>, <a href="http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/landing_chrome_mac.html?hl=en">chrome</a>, <a href="http://www.opera.com/">opera</a>, or <a href="http://www.apple.com/safari/">safari</a>), or download the video by clicking the download link below.</p>

        </div>

    </video>
```

Can anyone lend we some direction with this?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the stylesheet you can make a difference as well for different orientations

```
@media only screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    .yourclass{
    }
}

@media only screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    .yourclass{
    }
}
```

This allows you to have two definitions for the same class (or ID, or tag) and it should be updating your page dynamically when you turn the device to another orientation